# Why is this code throwing an output from a random other code in my project? How can I fix this?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, webdriver, pageobjects

I am new to Java and I might have messed up something in the code. But what is wrong here? I am trying to create objects for the elements in the home page which I have to test.

```
   package pageObjects;

      import org.openqa.selenium.By;
      import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
      import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class HomePage {

private static WebElement element;

public static void main(String args[], WebDriver driver){

    HomePage hp = new HomePage();
    hp.SignInButton(driver);
    hp.ImageButton(driver);
    System.out.println("Yup");
}

public WebElement SignInButton(WebDriver driver){

    element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In"));
    System.out.println("Yeua");
    return element;

}

public WebElement ImageButton(WebDriver driver){

    return element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images"));

}

  }
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is the "random output" you are getting and what you are expecting to see.

Comment: I am getting an output of a "Hello World" code which is also placed inside the project folder. I am trying to create the objects for the elements in the home page I am testing. This code should output the "Yup" and the "Yeua" which I have placed inside the objects.

Comment: It looks like you are running the wrong project.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the IDE you are using, you have to check the run configuration and see, which one is being executed.

If you do not have a valid `main()` to start with, most IDEs will execute the last file that you started with a valid `main()`.

Your `main()`has to many arguments `public static void main(String args[], WebDriver driver)`

Remove the `WebDriver driver`

Comment: This is what I am getting as an output when I remove the WebDriver driver argument.


        Error: Main method not found in class pageObjects.HomePage,                      please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: @SteroidKing666 What IDE are you using? Also if you remove the argument, you also have to remove everything in the main that is working with that variable.

Comment: I did remove everything related to that. Sorry I am not sure how to format the reply to a code.


inline` public static void main(String[] args) {
    HomePage hp = new HomePage();
    WebDriver driver = null;
    hp.SignInButton(driver);
    hp.ImageButton(driver);
    System.out.println("Yup");
}`

Comment: @SteroidKing666 So what is your IDE? Eclipse? NetBeans? IntelliJ? and make sure you saved the file and that you are editing the correct file (maybe you have a copy of the file and editing the wrong one). Hard to tell what's going on with just the info we have.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/466unt/why_is_my_pageobject_code_throwing_an_output_of_a/d02z19k You do not hae the package defined

Comment: It is defined. package pageObjects; Its at the top. I did not copy paste.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 I am pretty sure it's your project settings / run configuration. You still did not tell us which IDE you use. I also recommend learning how to compile and run your programms with the command line: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html