# Have asked this before but never could fix this. Response says Main Method not defined even with it defined?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The main package is named pageObjects. The main class is named HomePage. It returns two objects for the two elements in the page I am testing. I am testing a home page of a website for the two elements which are the login button and the image button. This is for a Selenium WebDriver Page Object Framework. I am learning Java and Selenium so it might be very silly looking :) But I would like to know why I am getting the response "Error: Main method not found in class pageObjects.HomePage, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
"

```
  package pageObjects;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class HomePage {

private static WebElement element;

public static void main(String[] args){

    HomePage hp = new HomePage();
    WebDriver driver = null;
    hp.SignInButton(driver);
    hp.ImageButton(driver);
    System.out.println("Yup");
}

public WebElement SignInButton(WebDriver driver){

    element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In"));
    System.out.println("Yeua");
    return element;

}

public WebElement ImageButton(WebDriver driver){

    return element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images"));

}

}
```

Response I am getting:

```
Error: Main method not found in class pageObjects.HomePage, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Purpose of the code: It should create two objects for the two elements in the page which I would be using later in a separate code for the package. All of it is going to be a part of the Selenium Page Object Model framework I am practicing while learning Java.

Comment: Is the other question still alive?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448860/why-is-this-code-throwing-an-output-from-a-random-other-code-in-my-project-how

Comment: Then don't repeat it trying to get attention please. Duplicates like this will get closed.

Comment: Start by fixing the obvious errors. For example, you are calling two methods, passing in your `driver'. In both of those methods, you then access driver without checking null and yet you never instantiated driver so it will surely fail.

Comment: can you first try to right and run HelloWorld programme successfully..so that would rollout the issues of compilation..if u r using eclipse there is option to do project cleanup.please do that and see

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is not problem with main method.. i will prefer clean once then rename this class to other name say HomePage_OldCopy and create new class by selecting main at the time of creation with same name as HomePage and then try.

You may face two issues as one is driver is null. Once initiated this driver then second issue is you may not find those web elements as there is no get method to navigate URL where you can find those elements.

```
public class HomePage {

public static WebElement element;
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args){

HomePage hp = new HomePage();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();

//please you get to navigate any URL where you can find below web elements

hp.SignInButton(driver).click(); //clicking on SIgn In web element
hp.ImageButton(driver).click(); //clicking on images link/web element
System.out.println("Yup");
}

public WebElement SignInButton(WebDriver driver){

element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In"));
System.out.println("Yeua");
return element;

}

public WebElement ImageButton(WebDriver driver){

return element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images"));

}

}
```

thank you,
murali